# "Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined" when adding firebase to chrome extension

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to add Firebase to a Chrome extension and am getting the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined", when I follow examples I am finding on the Internet (including all the answers I find on Stack Overflow).

My background.js file is only a few lines:

```js
var config = {
  apiKey: "x-x",
  authDomain: "xx",
  databaseURL: "xx",
  projectId: "xx",
  storageBucket: "xx",
  messagingSenderId: "xx"
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

The manifest is equally simple:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.32",
  "description": "test",
  "background": {
    "persistent": true,
    "scripts": [
      "background.js",
      "firebase-app.js",
      "firebase-firestore.js"
    ]
  },
  "short_name": "test",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],

  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://cdn.firebase.com https://*.firebaseio.com; object-src 'self'",
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

If I try to use firebase.js (taken from Angular 7 node_modules directory) instead of firebase-app.js & firebase-firestore.js (from firebase-bower-master), Chrome complains and says I should include only the packages for the specific functions I want to use.

Every example I find indicates that the js scripts should be automatically loaded into background.js and work fine.

What am I missing?

Thanks for your help!

Edward

Comment: The very first thing I'd try is changing the order of the scripts so `background.js` is last.

Comment: Chris - how did you get the JSON to format? I tried with (obviously) no success.....

Comment: Super!  The odd thing is that in my full app I have another js file that is included after background.js that works fine.  However, putting background.js last did the trick. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Cool; I wasn't 100% sure but too lazy to try myself ;) However it looks like if script A uses script B, then script B needs to be above script A. So there's nothing odd really about what you describe. background.js doesn't need to be *last*, but it needs to be below the firebase script. As for the formatting, indent by four spaces for code (it's basically Markdown).

Answer (score 0):

Per Chris' suggestion, putting background.js last did the trick.

```
  "background": {
    "persistent": true,
    "scripts": [
      "firebase-app.js",
      "firebase-firestore.js",
      "background.js"
    ]
  },
```

Comment: where did you get or download the other scripts from ... firebase-app.js & firebase-firestore.js